# Email Verification and Submitting value into database

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate email and it is also getting validated but the below php code is inserting the value into db even if the user has not entered the valid email. Please if anyone can help I am a beginner. Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="javascript">

function checkEmail() {
    var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus;
        return false;
    }
}
</script>


<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","xyz");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// print_r($_POST); 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    echo $user;
    $query = "INSERT INTO Newsletter VALUES('$user')"; 
    if(mysqli_query($con, $query)){ 
         echo "inserted";
    } else { 
         echo "fail";
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<input name="user" id="txtEmail" type="text" class="input-field" 
placeholder="Send us an email of your requirements and we will                  get          back    to you!!"></div>
<div>
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="input-button" value="subscribe" onclick='Javascript:checkEmail();'>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are using javascript: have to call the check on the form submitting. The PHP isn't involved in this. Post your `form` code.

Comment: So this question is not about php and mysql? It sounds like the problem is with your javascript. By the way, I'd recommend backend validation as well. Front end validation is great for usability, but backend validation is still important to ensure data validity.

Comment: `email.focus;`, it's `focus()`

Comment: I have also updated the form code please check. Thanks

Comment: Also note that it's better to use the form's `onsubmit` event instead. Otherwise the user can skip validation if they just press enter to submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to change the submit code .

CURRENT >>

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="input-button" value="subscribe" onclick='Javascript:checkEmail();'>
```

Change it to >>

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="input-button" value="subscribe" onclick='return checkEmail();'>
```

But ideally you should keep the function validation at the FORM onsubmit event instead of onclick event of the submit button.